# How to resume a recently paused activity in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I've searched for solutions, but none of what I've found helped.

Lets say I have three activities, MainActivity, Activity1, and Activity2. All of these activities extend AppCompactActivity.

In MainActivity this variable is defined: public static AppCompatActivity mainActivity;
and in the onCreate() method, mainActivity is initialized like so: mainActivity = this;

In MainActivity there is a button that launches Activity1, and in Activity1 there is a button that launches Activity2.

Now what I want to do is: to override the onBackPressed() of Activity2, to be able to resume from the same exact state of the object reference that is saved in the variable mainActivity.

In other words, I want to resume the activity mainActivity, not start a new one.

I hope you can help me out guys.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the onPause and onResume methods in Activity.
Check the Android documentation
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Answer (score 0):

You could set `noHistory` property to Activity1, so every time you back from Activity2, MainActivity is resumed.

See more info [here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: I think that may work, but I'm looking for a more general solution. Like what if I want to launch mainActivity from any other activity?